# jquery code not making links link

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body[class*=page-calendar-practices] #content-header h1#title").after("<div id='athletics_practice-schedule'><div id='inner-title'><a href='www.example.com' class='athletics_links'>GAMES</a><a href='www.example.com/games' class='athletics_links'>PRACTICES</a></div></div>");

});
```

This code creates the anchor links on the page as it should, but (in at least Google Chrome) they don't show up as links, just as text. Why is this?

Comment: It may be a CSS issue - a rule may be removing the default link color and underline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly because they're not proper URLs? You need to add "http://" before the domain name for an absolute URL.

http://jsfiddle.net/X3399/1/ -- Your code actually works fine, but the links don't point where you probably expected them to point.

Comment: Those are just placeholders for the real one. But either way, they should still show up as a link when you hover over it, right?

Comment: That depends. Is the hover effect produced by CSS or jQuery? If it's by CSS, then yes, it should. If it's by jQuery, then you probably need to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)-style events instead, since your links are being added to the DOM later.

Comment: No, everything is by jquery. I'll try out your suggestion, I've never used live() before.

Comment: To bind "live-style" hover events, use something like: `$(document).on('mouseenter','a',function(){...}).on('mouseleave','a',function(){...});` -- http://jsfiddle.net/X3399/2/

Comment: Oh, I've never used live() but I've used delegate(), which seems to be the same thing. But how would I do this? The creation of the html code above doesn't occur on an event such as 'click', so do I need to write two different pieces of code? One as quoted above and the other with a live() to set the links?   Oops, I just saw your post.

Comment: Ok, that works. But there's now one more issue. For correct positioning, I needed to use a negative margin to push this whole outer dive up. So, when I try to hover on the text in the link, its does nothing. When I hover a little below the text the text becomes underlined and becomes a link. Is there a way for me to have the mouse hover be on the top of the box? I already tried to change the select to the outer div.

Comment: That is a new question, and should be posted separately.